# How to install the Postgresql GUI using Homebrew?

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

PostgreSQL's graphical user interface app is missing from the ~/Applications folder when it is installed via Homebrew, the package manager for MacOS: `brew install postgresql`

Is there a way to tell brew to install the GUI?

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't have an inherent GUI.  Some installation methods might bundle some 3rd-party GUI along with PostgreSQL itself, but you haven't specified what alternative installation method you are comparing homebrew to, so we don't know what 3rd party GUI it is that you might be expecting to find.

Comment: [Which one](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_Clients) do you want to install?

Answer (score 3):

The PostgreSQL package does not include a GUI app. You need to install it separately.

Two of the most commonly utilized GUI tools are:

1. [PgAdmin4](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/): `brew install --cask pgadmin4`
2. [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.io/): `brew install --cask dbeaver-community`